# convert for swift 3 indexpath check

Tags: xcode, swift3

can someone help me change this to swift 3 please?

func tableView(_ detailCallListTable: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

```
    if (detailCallListTable.isEditing && indexPath == false){
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none;
    }
```

indexPath == false creates an error:

Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IndexPath' and 'Bool'

thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you want to check by doing `indexPath == false`? What do you think it will check?

Comment: There is a no meaning of above code. What do you want to achieve using above code?

Comment: Instead of checking indexPath == false, check if its nil, eg. indexPath == nil
IndexPath is not a boolean, its a struct in swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sweeper suggests, testing if `indexPath` is `false` does not really make sense.

`indexPath` has two relevant properties: `row` and `section`

So, it looks like the new Swift compiler is catching a pre-existing bug; i.e. this code wasn't ever really valid.

Ask yourself if it you need to instead test the value of `row` or `section` to determine what `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` to return.